# Is `Context` appropriate to be used to implement DI?

Tags: reactjs, dependency-injection

I used Angular which uses the DI pattern very heavily.

I want to put it into my design of a REACT project. I intuitively think `Context` in REACT is the right way there.

Here is the demo:
https://codepen.io/singhijohn/pen/NWWLzBQ?editors=1010

```
class UserService {
    async login() {
        console.log("login")
    }
}

const userService = new UserService()

const ServicesContext = React.createContext({ userService })

const App = (props) => {
    return <ServicesContext.Provider value={{ userService }}>
      <Main title="hello" />
    </ServicesContext.Provider>
}

const Inject = (C) => {
    return props => {
      const value = React.useContext(ServicesContext)
      return React.createElement(C, { ...value, ...props })
    }
}

const Main = Inject(({ userService, title }) => {
    return <>
        <h3>{title}</h3>
        <button onClick={() => {
           userService.login()
        }}>use service</button>
    </>
})
```

Comment: Use [Higher Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) instead of Context for DI.

Comment: The function `Inject` here is the HOC.  It seems `Context` here is unnecessary. ~

Comment: yes that's what I'm saying. No need to have a separate service class. Just put whatever capability you need to inject as part of the HOC.